# Coregistration for training and validation

Tags: remote-sensing, validation, coregistration

If I want to use a 30-m raster as an independent validation dataset for a remote sensing analysis of 10-m and 20-m satellite imagery bands, do I need to coregister the 30-m raster with the 10-m and 20-m satellite image?